# Open a View Controller when already another View Controller is in progress

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a view controller with a tableview this view controller has a button called favourites in a toolbar at the bottom. Now when you click on a cell this opens another view controller called videoviewcontroller, this view controller can be dragged diagonally so you can see the tableview view controller. Now that the videoviewcontroller is dragged down you can see the tableviewcontroller and the favourites button, but when i click on the favourites button Nothing happens, the favourites button should open another view controller while the videoviewcontroller is still in progress.

Why doesn't the favourites viewcontroller open?

```
    RecentlyViewedViewController *recentlyViewedViewController = NULL;
    recentlyViewedViewController= [[RecentlyViewedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecentlyViewedViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:recentlyViewedViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: You can only have 1 ModalViewController presented at one time on the Controller Hierarchy. Consider just making these "over" views UIViews, and letting the Tableview manage them.

Comment: Ok so what your saying is use UIViews rather than ModelViewControllers

Comment: @Wayfarer, if i have a table cell in the main view controller then have a ui view to handle the tableview in favourites uiview how would i handle both tableviews